# .Net updating Session object side effects

Tags: c#, session, webforms

I'm having some strange (to me at least) functionality with `Session` objects in my .Net Webforms project. I'm passing objects around in `Sessions` and I'm not using any `global` variables. I have a method described below:

```
 private int Foo()
 {
     RmRule ruleInEdit = (RmRule)Session["ruleInEdit"];
     //here ruleInEdit.subjectAreaID=0
     bool isValid = Validate();
     if (isValid)
     {
        //do some stuff
        //here ruleInEdit.subjectAreaID is 10 instead of 0
        //the Validate function modified the ruleInEdit object 
      }

    //other code
  }

   private bool Validate()
   {
       bool isValid;
       //check some stuff
       RmRule rule = (RmRule)Session["ruleInEdit"];
       rule.subjectAreaID = 10;
       Session["ruleInEdit"] = rule;
       return isValid;
    }
```

I thought that the value of subjectAreaID should still be 0 but clearly I'm misunderstanding something. How (or Why) does .Net update the `ruleInEdit` object automatically when I write the object back to the `Session`.

- In the original method `Foo`, shouldn't I have to force ruleInEdit to read the session again to get the updated object and properties?
- Is this object tied to the session scope because of the way that I initialized it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to write the object back to the session collection, it never leaves.

There is only one instance of the object, it's not copied when you read it from the session collection. Any change you make to the object is instantly visible to all code that looks at the same instance (i.e. the same session).

What's stored in the session collection is just a reference to the object. The object itself is stored on the heap.

Comment: +0. Missing mentioning of in-proc/out-of-proc differences.

Answer (score 3):

When you are using InProc (by default) session storage, then there is no serialization occured. You are operation by your custom class, which is reference type. So when your method Validate retrieves an object from session, in reality it's just a pointer where you are changing original object.
In another words object of type RmRule is the same in Foo and Validate methods.

Behavior expected by you will be after switching application settings to store session in SQL server for example.